# Using libpam pwhistory module to update the opasswd file

Tags: c, pam

I'm working on a project where it is necessary to check a user's password for uniqueness against historical passwords, and add old passwords to a list of historical passwords. To accomplish this I want to read and write to the opasswd file with the pam_pwhistory module. I don't want to update the user's password at all, just to check whether it is unique or not, and write their existing password to the opasswd file. The user has just been prompted for their password, and I have access to the new password, so I don't want to have to prompt the user for it again.

As far as I can tell, there are two ways to do this:

1. Use pam functions (pam_start, pam_chauthtok, pam_end), and interpret the prompts '(current) UNIX password: ', 'New password: ' and 'Retype new password: '. Only include pam_pwhistory.so in the PAM chain for this application. This feels very ugly as these prompts are obviously intended to be interactive, and could be renamed in future. I'd also like to avoid having to maintain an extra PAM configuration file if necessary.
2. Use pamc to communicate directly with the pam_pwhistory module. I have not had much luck with this approach and it doesn't seem to be well documented. Should I be using this API at all?
3. Is there a 3rd option? How would you approach this?

Thanks very much for any help!